# Many To One relation inside Embeddable , Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, entity

I have a scenario where an `Embeddable` class in hibernate uses an`Entity`. According to various answers I found on SO and other links, we can write `@ManyToOne, @OneToMany` inside an `Embeddable` class.

But doing this gives me `HibernateMappingExeption`

Consider the following example:
I have two Entities and an Embeddable class as under:

**Entity A**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int a_id;

    @ElementCollection
    @JoinTable(name = "embeded_class_table", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "a_id"))
    private List<EmbeddedClass> embeddedClass;
```

**Entity B**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int b_id;
```

**Embeddable Class which uses Entity B**

```
@Embeddable
public class EmbeddableClass {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    private B b;
```

The error I am getting is as under:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: app.model.B, at table: embeded_class_table, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(b)]
```

Could anyone please suggest if I am using these stuff correctly and if yes, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your scenario I tried the following I didn't get any issues:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int a_id;

    @ElementCollection
    @JoinTable(name = "embeded_class_table", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "a_id"))
    private List<EmbeddableClass> embeddedClass;

    public int getA_id() {
        return a_id;
    }

    public void setA_id(int a_id) {
        this.a_id = a_id;
    }

    public List<EmbeddableClass> getEmbeddedClass() {
        return embeddedClass;
    }

    public void setEmbeddedClass(List<EmbeddableClass> embeddedClass) {
        this.embeddedClass = embeddedClass;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int b_id;
}

@Embeddable
public class EmbeddableClass {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    private B b;

    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }


}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">xxxx</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">elias</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="com.springex.dto.A"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.springex.dto.B"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.springex.dto.EmbeddableClass"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: this did not work, I think the issue is with relation between `EnbeddableClass` and `Entity B`, as the exception says: `Could not determine type for: app.model.B, at table: embeded_class_table, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(b)]`

Comment: I have changed my answer. Can you see did you follow the same thing?

Comment: This works! Thanks. But why do we need to add `(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`, I dont understand this

Comment: Entity relationships defined with CascadeType.All will ensure that all persistence events such as persist, refresh, merge and remove that occur on the parent, will be passed to the child.
For example if I had an object Book that contained a List of pages and I add a page object within this list. 
If the @OneToMany annotation defining the association between Book and Page is marked as CascadeType.All, persisting the Book would result in the Page also being persisted to the database.

Comment: Ok I understand that but that is not compulsory right?

Comment: Since we are not using @Transactional, after any call to service method, transaction will be commit and session cleared. When you try to save entity, "B"object is not detected in session and managed as transient instance and issues the following exception
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.technicalkeeda.entities.B
so in order to avoid this exception I have used the cascade = CascadeType.ALL