# How to define mapping between two embeddable classes?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

Suppose i have two entity classes with embeddable/composite keys...
Eg.

```
@Entity 
public class X
{
     @EmbeddedId private Embed id;
     ......

@Embeddable public class Embed
{
    private int a;
    private int b;
   .......

@Entity 
public class Y
{
     @EmbeddedId private YEmbed id;
     ......

@Embeddable public class YEmbed
{
    private int a1;
    private int b1;
   .......
```

Now in the above scenario i want to define some kind of mapping eg. OnetoOne or ManytoOne or any other mapping between Tables X and Y using composite key fields a with a1 or b with b1 ???

How can i achieve this in spring-jpa/hibernate ???

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43185365/many-to-one-relation-inside-embeddable-hibernate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Many To One relation inside Embeddable , Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43185365/many-to-one-relation-inside-embeddable-hibernate)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @JohnCamerin but my question is somewhat different....

The post you suggested is having embedded class for only one of the entity but in my case both the entity have embeddable classes and i want to define some kind of mapping between them using their embedded classes....

:)